# Why isn't e.Handled stopping the beeps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got multiple text and combo boxes in my Visual Studio 2012 project, and I have the keydown set to execute different events on Enter being pressed. And, there's that useless, stupidly annoying beep, every time. I've looked all over, found e.Handled = true and e.SuppressKeyPress = true solutions, and they're doing not a damn thing.

The code from one of my combobox is:

```
  private void cmbNavigate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(cmbNavigate.Text);
        }
    }
```

I've tried with the Suppress and the standard Handled and neither works, it just keeps beeping away mockingly at me.

Comment: It's a default Windows setting, that lets you know that it's not multiline, and so warns you that Enter is not, in fact, going to get you to the next line of anything. I know I can change the setting in Windows, but that just helps me, not my users.

Comment: What UI framework, Winform, WPF, ASP?

Comment: It's a basic Windows Form.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in e.suppressKeyPress=true and see if your code reaches here.

Comment: `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` in KeyDown() kills the beep on my system.  Running VS2013 on Win 8.1 x64.  Like Musfiqur rahman said, make sure your event is wired up and actually firing.

Comment: I would like to add this comment to help others from being made confused by this question **In fact, the code of the OP works OK, we just need `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `e.Handled = true;` in addition to `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Comment: It worked. Either alone didn't work, doing both got the job done! Thanks!

Comment: @AarronDixon your code **works** for me, don't even need `e.Handled = true`

Comment: It's just one of those weird, esoteric things about the .NET Framework. :)